# Error message: pointer to function

Tags: visual-c++

I get an error message saying expression must have (pointer-to-) function type. what am i doing wrong? i just started coding, i know i suck lol. I don't understand how to get the formula for the distance to work.

```
#include <cmath>    //headerfile
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

    enter code here

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double d;
    double t;
    double g;
    char choice ='y';



    //output numbers to console


    while (choice == 'y' || choice =='Y')
    {
        cout<<"Please input a value for the time"<< endl<<endl;
        cin>>t;

        g = 32;
        d = (g)(t*t);

        if (t<0)
            cout<<"You cannot have a negative time"<<endl<<endl;

        else


        cout<<setw(8)<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<"\n""The distance the ball has fallen is "<<d<<" feet"<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Would you like to run this again? y for yes, any other key for no."<< endl<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<endl;


    }
system ("Pause");
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If (g)(t*t) is supposed to be a normal multiplication operation, then it should be g*t*t.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `g` is a double, but you are using it as if it was a pointer to a function (`d = (g)(t*t);`). If what you really want is to multiply `t*t` by `g`, you forgot an `*`:

```
d = (g)*(t*t);
```